# weird rigging problem

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting

I made a little guy and rigged his legs with an *Armature* modifier. I've done the weight painting manually. However, when I attempt to move his leg, it doesn't follow the armature like it should. Any fix?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include a .blend file?

Comment: It looks like the right leg of the mesh is not totally (or not only) rigged to the right part of the armature. But yes, a .blend file may help to check that.

Comment: That looks like a weight-painting issue, like the leg mesh is 50% weighted to the right leg bone, and 50% weighted to the left, or some other set of bones.  Try weight painting with 'Add' mode and make sure your brush is set to 1.0, and 'Clean Weights' after you're done.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/xnixcls52bghyjl/gabennn+n+n+nn+.blend1 Did it on mediafire cause its above 30 mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your weight painting. Every single one of your bones has too much influence over the mesh. Luckily, there is an easy solution.

### Solution

First, select the mesh and delete the *Armature Deform* object modifier. Next, <kbd>RMB</kbd> select the mesh, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> select the armature (make sure both are in *Object Mode*) and key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the parenting menu. Select *With Automatic Weights* under *Armature Deform* (pictured below). It may take a while to parent because of the high vertex count. Afterward, your mesh should now have reassigned weights and move perfectly.

[image]

*The Parenting Menu.*

I do not have media fire, so I could not include a .blend file. If you have any question, though, ask away.

**UPDATE:**

The use of a *Decimate* modifier set to *Planar* and *Angle Limit: 6.4* can solve the **Bone Heat Weighting Failed** issue. Read more about in my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54105/bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones/54119#54119). Download a rigged and finished .blend file below.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, it said, it failed to find solutions for one ore more heights or something like that, thanks for the help for now though, trying to fix it

Comment: Posted the good blend for anyone that could help me, sitll cant do it

Comment: Still cant do it

Comment: @gabe I answered your newer question and updated this one. This time, I included a .blend file, so you should have no issues. If you believe that my answers here and also [there](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54105/bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones/54119#54119) helped, please consider accepting one or preferably both. I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Your mesh have too many unrelated bone influences.  Your best bet at this point:

1. Get into weight painting mode
2. Select all the bones
3. Hit `W` >> `Assign Automatic from Bones`.
4. `Viewport menu` >> `Weights` >> `Normalize All`.

If you do make any adjustments, make sure the brush is set to 'Add' and make the power 1.0.  The lion's share of weight-painting can be done this way.

Slightly unrelated: the model has way too much geometry for the detail that it has, and you can likely half, even quarter the amount of faces you have without losing any meaningful features.  This will ease up on your filesize, and viewport performance.  You should also give your bones meaningful names (Femur.R, not Bone.004).

Comment: how do you select all bones?

Comment: If you have a bone already selected, hit `a` twice.  If none are selected hit `a` once.