# bone heat weighting failed to find solution for one or more bones

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I am guessing you guys get this a lot, but I've tried everything to fix the **Bone Heat Weighting Failed** error. I have no idea what to do, so if you guys can somehow fix this, then you're amazing.

.blend file below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The use of a *Decimate* object modifier can aid in solving your problem. Note that in my rigging of your mesh, I changed the names and added a bone between the feet. This can be used to move all bones, as all other bones are parented to it.

### Solution

Go to the *Object modifier* tab in the *Properties panel* and delete any *Armature* modifiers. Add a *Decimate* modifier from the dropdown. Select *Planar* from the three options and set the *Angle Limit:* value to 6.4. It should look something like this:

[image]

*Apply* the *Decimate* modifier. Next, select your mesh and then your armature. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the parenting pop up menu and select *With Automatic Weights* under the *Armature Deform* section. The option should look like this:

[image]

After a second or two, it should be finished. Here is a .blend file if you want to just download it:

[image]

Comment: so it didnt work because it had too many vertices?

Answer (score 3):

You need to " set origin to geometry" for the mesh.

The button is located in the (t)toolshelf-->Edit-->SetOrigin