# Why does my character model bunch up when posing?

Tags: rigging

I make a fan model of a game character, but when I pose his fingers they bunch up.

I can't understand why it does that, if anyone has an explanation, please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Short answer - Weight Painting. If you need more, post your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com). Also see [weird rigging problem](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54059/weird-rigging-problem).

Comment: I used the auto weight setting,and then it scrambled my vertex groups.

Comment: It should have. That's kind of the point. Did it not improve anything? If it didn't please consider posting your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) and __editing__ your question to add the generated link. Notify me when done.

Comment: I did it,and it screwed up the vertex groups,so I fixed the groups and sure than enough,it  started screwing up again.

Comment: Posted the blend,please send it back to me when it's fixed,no changes to the mesh,just please fix the weights,and no releasing it to YouTube or Steam.

Comment: Edited my answer. If it works, please consider accepting it by pressing the checkmark in the upper left-hand corner of my answer. It would help me greatly and make me very happy.

Comment: Okay,I didn't mean the entire mesh,I just meant please correct the weights to the finger vertex groups.

Comment: The finger has only two segments,I'm gonna add a third and see if it's any different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's me again User27033.
I figured it out.
What I did was that I duplicated and separated the hands and hand bones, then I parented the hands to the bones but you have to separate the bones first by the left hand and then the right.
Then after you have used ***Armature Deform > With Automatic Weights***, change the parent on the Armature Modifier in the Modify tab, delete the attached bones to the hands that have been detached from the mesh but not the main bone group and then join the hands back to the mesh and rejoin the vertices.

Answer (score 0):

The weights probably aren't proper. Click on the mesh and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then click the bone you're moving. The more red an area is, the more it's influenced by that bone. Play around with it until you achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but the following is my procedure.

I <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> selected the mesh and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> selected the armature. I keyed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and chose *Armature Deform > With Automatic Weights*. I did not do any additional weight painting or anything. I was able to produce the following results.

*Mesh:*

[image]

*Rendered, 19 Samples:*

[image]

.blend file:

[image]